# Error Pushing Email Quick Action to Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, quickaction

I'm using SFDX to push source code to a scratch org and getting the following error with an email quick action:

```
> Error 
> force-app\main\default\quickActions\Case.Send_Email.quickAction-meta.xml
> Send Email is disabled or activities are not allowed. Enable Send
> Email and allow activities, then try again.
```

Deliverability in the scratch org is set to "All Email".  What else am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue.  Turns out Email-to-Case needs to be enabled even though I was dealing with an outbound email action.

Update: here's the setting I had to add:

```
"settings": {
    "caseSettings": {
      "emailToCase": {
        "enableEmailToCase": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some project-scratch-def options are ignored by scratch:org:create, i see randomly such error with "ContactToMultipleAccount" for example

Try with a new scratch org :)

Comment: Tried that as well.